# how to print logs into only one file by google glog

Tags: c++, glog

I'm now using google glog. When I'm debugging the program, every time the process restart, a new log file generated, identified by the new pid as filename's sufix, like this

```
ied_config.20131220-142934.4524
ied_config.20131220-171227.3948
ied_config.20131225-170117.7032
ied_config.20131225-170131.5200
ied_config.20131225-171450.7820
ied_config.20131225-172336.4116
ied_config.20131225-172924.6120
ied_config.20131225-173000.2980
ied_config.20131225-173037.1960
ied_config.20131225-173144.7304
ied_config.20131226-095843.1012
smv_client.20131219-082120.7184
smv_client.20131219-162339.5508
smv_client.20131219-163055.6156
smv_client.20131219-163155.4892
smv_client.20131219-163206.5576
smv_client.20131219-163216.6340
smv_client.20131219-163236.6952
smv_client.20131219-163307.7940
smv_client.20131219-163317.4920
smv_client.20131219-163347.6556
smv_client.20131219-163408.5124
smv_client.20131219-163428.2644
smv_client.20131219-163448.6040
smv_client.20131219-163529.6948
smv_client.20131219-163539.1592
smv_client.20131219-163549.3776
smv_client.20131219-172949.5412
smv_client.20131219-173000.4180
smv_client.20131219-173010.7432
smv_client.20131220-170628.636
smv_client.20131220-170930.3904
smv_client.20131226-095841.1296
```

I want to join these log just into one file for each program, I can't file the configuration for the glog ,any helps?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the name of log files, you may need to call SetLogDestination():

```
google::SetLogDestination(google::INFO, "/var/tmp/another_destination.INFO");
```

Comment: This still appends date and time to log file.  How do I turn that off?

Comment: @empty have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

From release 0.5 on May 8, 2021

> Allow a log file to be simply named "foobar.log" with no appended
> string #124

google::SetLogDestination(google::INFO, "/var/tmp/another_destination.INFO");
FLAGS_timestamp_in_logfile_name = false;